# Asp net core web app runtime error after publish

Tags: asp.net-core, web-config, runtime

So immediately after publishing my asp net core app it gives me the classic runtime error. I tried these modifications to the web.config file, from the internet (separate and combined):

```
<configuration>
        <system.webServer>
            <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
            <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
        </system.webServer>
        <system.web>
            <compilation debug="true"></compilation>
            <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

So far they've done nothing. I still get the same error page telling me to set customErrors to Off. This also happens when I create a random new Asp net core web app (mvc) in Visual studio and publish that one. Tried it with a asp core 2.1 app as well.

Any idea?

Comment: Do you have access to the Event Viewer on the server? The error message often shows up there as well.

Comment: I don't. There's a log folder that sometimes spawns an empty log file though

Comment: Ah....what is your application pool set to? No Managed Code? .NET 4?

Comment: It's set to ASP.NET 4.0 (Integrated Pipeline). I don't see anything on managed code so that's gotta be default. I just tried a new 2.1 app and now it just shows a 500 error. The log file doesn't seem empty anymore, the online file manager says it's 2KB, when I download it it's just an empty file though

Comment: I also checked my hosting plan: it clearly states: ASP.NET 4.7 | 4.6.x | 4.5.x | 4.0
ASP.NET 3.5 | 2.0
MVC
ASP.NET Core 1.x | 2.x | 3.x

Comment: If you're doing an ASP.NET Core app and running on .NET Core, then you need No Managed Code, you won't need .NET Framework at all.

Comment: Finally fixed it! (Oh well... it works with an empty project). Appearantly I hadn't given the FTP account a default directory, so it published outside of the website.com folder